# Issue in running Selenium Server instances in java program

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to run selenium server instances in my java code. This works when I run manually in CMD or trigger batch file manually. But when I execute these commands in my java code. i am ending up with issue. Can someone tell me what is wrong with the syntax I mentioned here.

```
java -jar \"" + ff.getCanonicalPath().replace("\\", "//") + "//Selenium APIs//selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar\"
-role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=chrome,maxInstances=
"+ _ThreadCount +" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=\"chromedriver.exe\"";
```

Comment: is the slash at that end of "...Selenium APIs//selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar\" supposed to be there?

Comment: I am just wondering why you are using all of those pram's on startup rather than specifying a config.json?

Comment: i had it as batch file which worked. now im trying to include this in code so that i dont have to manually trigger the batch file. But now im facing this issue. when i copied the command and tried in cmd manually i got this following error."Error building the config :-browser format is key1=value1,key2=value2 maxInstanc
es=3-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver.exe doesn't follow that format."